# Understanding behavior when convolving/deconvolving with a Gaussian of different width

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, convolution, gaussian

I'm fairly new to StackExchange so I hope my formatting is correct!

I've been trying to better understand the effects of convolution/deconvolution via FFT on Python.

Currently, I have a waveform and a Gaussian PDF of σ=14. Deconvolving them via FFT gives [this underlying signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAXLA.jpg).
If I take that underlying signal and convolve it with a Gaussian with the same parameters, I get the original waveform back, as expected.

However, the current issue I'm trying to work through is why I'm getting such a drastic change in the shape of my new waveform when I convolve the underlying signal with a Gaussian with a different σ: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSX2L.jpg

If I change σ from 14 (original parameter for the Gaussian used to deconvolve with the original waveform) to 12, I see more fluctuations in the tail of the new waveform, and more erratic behavior, but the overall shape remains similar to the original waveform's shape.
But, when I change σ from 14 to 20 or from 14 to 10 and convolve that Gaussian with the underlying signal, the resultant waveform looks **nothing** like the original waveform.

What could be causing these drastic changes? Is it some underlying property of the Gaussian PDF? I've got a fairly good grasp on the mathematics of convolution/deconvolution and FFT/iFFT, but I'm hoping that someone can please help me understand what is causing these changes in waveform shape! Thank you so much.

```py
#reading in the arrays from the txt file for the waveform

    mu = 9,990
    sig = 14
    totArea = 0
    time_array = [] 
    charge_array = []

    for i in range(len(file)):
        t = f[i][0]
        a = f[i][1]
        totArea += a
    tot = totArea * 3.3

#defining a Gaussian function with given mu and sigma

    def gaussfn(t,sig,mu):
        return np.exp((-(t-mu)**2)/(2*sig**2))

    result_orig = integrate.quad(lambda t:gaussfn(t,sig,mu),
    (mu-3*sig),(mu+3*sig))
    amp_orig = tot/result_orig[0]
    array_orig = amp_orig * gaussfn(time_array,sig,mu)

#deconvolving waveform and Gaussian via FFT to get the underlying signal

    gauss_orig_fft = np.fft.fft(array_orig)
    waveform_fft = np.fft.fft(charge_array)
    decon_orig = waveform_fft/gauss_orig_fft

    signal = np.fft.ifft(decon_orig) 

#defining a new Gaussian function of a different width

    new_sig = 10
    def gaussfn(t,new_sig,mu):
        return np.exp((-(t-mu)**2)/(2*new_sig**2))

    result_new = integrate.quad(lambda t:gaussfn(t,new_sig,mu),
    (mu-3*new_sig),(mu+3*new_sig))
    amp_new = tot/result_new[0]
    array_new = amp_new * gaussfn(time_array,new_sig,mu)

#using FFT to convolve the underlying signal (above) with a
Gaussian of a different sigma to get a new waveform

    gauss_new_fft = np.fft.fft(array_new)
    signal_fft = np.fft.fft(signal)
    convolution_new = signal_fft * gauss_new_fft
    new_waveform = np.fft.ifft(convolution_new)
```

Comment: Please show your code. It makes no sense to get such a wavy signal back from a convolution with a Gaussian. You are talking about convolution, not deconvolution? These are very different things!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm deconvolving a waveform with a Gaussian of sigma = 14 to get the underlying signal. Then, I'm convolving that signal with a Gaussian of a different sigma to get a new waveform.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I added my code above.

Comment: What values does `time_array` have? Does `(mu-3*sig),(mu+3*sig)` fit inside it for all the sigma you tried?

Comment: @CrisLuengo My time array is 128 elements. It starts at 9923.82423983 ns and ends at 10342.9242398 ns, with a 3.3 ns step size. My mu is 9,990 ns and (mu-3*sig), (mu+3*sig) does fit inside the time array for the values I tried!

Comment: Oh, so when you say sigma=10, it's actually about 3 samples. Yes, that matches with your results, given the input. But I think that the deconvolve waveform is purely noise. I'll write up a short answer to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you very much for your assistance! I was skeptical of whether my signal was actually meaningful or was just noise, so I appreciate you explaining that. I will definitely take your comments into consideration! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the deconvolution:

```
decon_orig = waveform_fft/gauss_orig_fft
```

is incredibly noise-sensitive. Plot `gauss_orig_fft`. You'll see it is nearly zero over a large frequency region (these are the high frequencies). Especially at high frequencies, there typically is little signal content, meaning that the noise dominates here. By dividing these frequencies by such a small value, you are enhancing this noise very strongly. Thus, your deconvolve signal is dominated by noise. Note the magnitude of your deconvolve signal, it is an order of magnitude larger than the input!

To avoid this, look into [the Wiener filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution). It does basically the same thing you are doing, but regularizes the result to avoid enhancing noise.

---

Regarding the output of the Gaussian filtering, you'll notice that for sigmas close to 14, you approximate your original signal again. For smaller sigmas, there's less smoothing and the noise keeps dominating. For larger sigmas, everything is suppressed more, but there's still a bit of noise left. Unfortunately we cannot see the magnitude of the signal being reduced because your convolution kernel is not normalized. You should divide `array_new` by its sum, so that it sums up to 1. This makes it so that the mean signal value remains the same before and after filtering, and will allow you to compare the magnitudes of the signal before and after filtering.

The second issue is that your kernel is not centered around the origin. This causes a shift of the signal after filtering. Because of the periodicity of the DFT, the signal basically wraps around. In the DFT, the origin is the first sample of the signal. The signal being periodic, the Gaussian would appear partly on the left end and partly on the right end, such that if you repeat the signal you can see the full Gaussian. With the kernel defined in this way, no shift should appear after applying the filter.